# Включения в PHP

Tags: include, php

Будет ли подключаться файл посредством include при компиляции скрипта - я окружу этот include условием:

```
if(условие) {
    include(file);
}
```

Если условие не выполнено, то подключится file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нет, не подключится. Это функция, а не директива.

Answer (score 3):

будет подгружаться только тогда, когда будет выполнено условие

Answer (score 1):

```
<php
   $ok = 'true' ;
     if($ok == 'true'){
      //если $ok = true то :
       echo 'всё ок';

        }else{
         //если $ok не равно true то :
          include('file.php')
       }
           ?>
```